# How to clear previous API request using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Have one button when clicking in lower version it sends request `/api/accept`. After upgrading it sends the same request. But in latest version the API request varies `/api/acceptconfirm`.

Could you please help me to clear the previous API requests from browser using selenium

Comment: Used driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() to delete the cookies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed("Cookie name");`

Please try the above code and try again

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and try again

Code:: python

```
del driver.requests
print (len(driver.requests)) # 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).